# XMLParser skipping to the last tag in a set of tags

Tags: c#, .net, xml, datatable, xml-parsing

I am reading an XML file into a datatable like this:

```
DataTable dt = XMLParser.XMLRead.ReadeFormXMLFile(filePath, "my:myFields");
```

however it is not capturing ALL the fields.

There are multiple practitionerlastnames and practitionerfirstnames and practitionerNPIs:

```
 <my:group1>
    <my:group2>
      <my:PractitionerFirstName>Joe</my:PractitionerFirstName>
      <my:PractitionerLastName>Limits</my:PractitionerLastName>
      <my:PractitionerNPI>0987654321</my:PractitionerNPI>
      <my:PractitionerDegree>MD</my:PractitionerDegree>
    </my:group2>
    <my:group2 xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2012-02-06T05:56:10">
       <my:PractitionerFirstName>Him</my:PractitionerFirstName>
       <my:PractitionerLastName>Haw</my:PractitionerLastName>
       <my:PractitionerNPI>1234567890</my:PractitionerNPI>
       <my:PractitionerDegree>PA</my:PractitionerDegree>
     </my:group2>
     <my:group2 xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2012-02-06T05:56:10">
        <my:PractitionerFirstName>Mike</my:PractitionerFirstName>
        <my:PractitionerLastName>Kim</my:PractitionerLastName>
        <my:PractitionerNPI>1234567890</my:PractitionerNPI>
        <my:PractitionerDegree>DO</my:PractitionerDegree>
     </my:group2>
     <my:group2 xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2012-02-06T05:56:10">
       <my:PractitionerFirstName>Vanilla </my:PractitionerFirstName>
       <my:PractitionerLastName>Ice</my:PractitionerLastName>
       <my:PractitionerNPI>1231231231</my:PractitionerNPI>
       <my:PractitionerDegree>MD</my:PractitionerDegree>
     </my:group2>
     <my:group2 xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2012-02-06T05:56:10">
       <my:PractitionerFirstName>Kim</my:PractitionerFirstName>
       <my:PractitionerLastName>John</my:PractitionerLastName>
       <my:PractitionerNPI>1234567890</my:PractitionerNPI>
       <my:PractitionerDegree>DO</my:PractitionerDegree>
     </my:group2>
  </my:group1>
```

however they are not being included. What it is currently doing is taking the LAST record in `group2` and ignoring all the records preceeding this one:

```
<my:PractitionerFirstName>Kim</my:PractitionerFirstName>
<my:PractitionerLastName>John</my:PractitionerLastName>
<my:PractitionerNPI>1234567890</my:PractitionerNPI>
<my:PractitionerDegree>DO</my:PractitionerDegree>
```

**question**: what would cause XML parser to grab only the last record from `group2` and omit everything else ?

Comment: please explain downvote and i am more than happy to change/add information

Comment: i don't know why you got downvotes. question tho: are the fields ignored the ones with a custom namespace? that is probably related to why (i don't have xmlparse experience btw)

Comment: @payo thanks so much for your response. i am new to XML so i dont know what that means :)

Comment: I read the sample xml too quickly. Try to reduce your example xml to a minimal set where the error repro's. Then, explain clearly which field is skipped or missing.

Comment: @payo thank you. i revised slightly detailing exaclty what is happening

Comment: I want to help you create a better SO question, your question is really not the minimal set needed to repro the problem. consider saying: "if i have `<group2><name>foo</name></group2><group2><name>bar</name></group2>` - the first group2 name 'foo' is skipped. But before you make this change, actually test it, find the MINIMAL problem set, and then ask here what is wrong

Comment: i just revised thank you for your help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10625/discussion-between-payo-and--)

Comment: It is not really possible to answer this question because the XML is parsed by `XMLParser.XMLRead.ReadeFormXMLFile` which is a method you or your organization wrote.

Comment: @MartinLiversage you should make that the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(filePath);
var list = root.Elements().Select(x => new
    {
        FirstName = x.Get("PractitionerFirstName", string.Empty),
        LastName = x.Get("PractitionerLastName", string.Empty),
        NPI = x.Get("PractitionerNPI", string.Empty),
        Degree = x.Get("PractitionerDegree", string.Empty)
    }).ToArray();
```

This works using the xml you provided.  I'm using the [Get extension method from here](https://github.com/ChuckSavage/XmlLib/blob/master/XElementExtensions.cs).